# Feel Management Stress test

Tags: performance-testing, stress-testing, webapplicationstresstool

I am working on a fleet management system that track a fleet fo ambulance using tracking device "Teltonika FMXXXX".

The system should finally operate almost 1400 ambulance, recording their history (Position, speed, ...) and online tracking.

I need to do a stress test on the server. I need to ensure that the 1400 devices will operate probably and the server can handle them.

I need to know how to simulate 1400 devices that send there data packet through TCP protocol?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to write a basic teltonika GSM-GPS module emulation program that connects to your server and send some fake location etc as many times as you want.

In order to do that you have to read your FM-xxxxx device protocol and see how teltonika's protocol works.

Usually those kind of device protocols are proprietary and you have to ask the ventor (teltonika) to provide you more info about the protocol, in order to implement the whole communication scenario.

you can take a look at this pdf [Teltonika FM Protocol](http://sourceforge.net/p/opengts/discussion/579834/thread/6fd0ffe8/6213/attachment/FMXXXX%20Protocols%20v2.10.pdf)